# How to start then repeatedly extend a json file list

Tags: json, python-3.x

My python is rusty, and I am trying to figure out how to start an empty json file then append to the json file (hopefully over and over again). Here is how I start a file:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    # old bad code: json.dump(list(), f)
    d = json.dumps(list())
    json.dump(d, f)
```

The file `foo.txt` has a simple, empty list in it. How do I manage to extend this lists with other lists. For example, say I want to extend `[]` with `list('abc')` such that I append `list('abc')` to the file which then contains `['a', 'b', 'c']` and then repeat with `list('efg')` producing `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` and so on?

For starters, I cannot get 'foo.txt' to load. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as feedsjson:
    feeds = json.load(feedsjson)
```

But it gives me, `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`. What is the simple cookbook recipe for starting a json file with an empty list, then adding to the list over time?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list(), f)
    
with open('foo.txt') as jf:
    letters = json.load(jf)
    letters.extend(list('abc'))
    
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(letters, f)
```

My mistake was the failure to read the data, change the data, then re-write the file